# jQuery to PHP: Add a selector class to children elements if more than one

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

Is it possible to implement the same thing than the jQuery code below in PHP?

I use it to hide errors made during importing products from wholesaler.

Here is the jQuery code I use:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('.woocommerce-product-details__short-description:has(p:nth-of-type(2)) p').addClass('ukryj-klase-krotki');
});
```

**How does it work:**

jQuery checks if in product short description is more than one `<p>` element. If there is more - it adds class 'ukryj-klase-krotki' to all `<p>` elements. Then I add CSS class to hide first `<p>` element generated in product short description so the only one I want is visible:

CSS code:

```css
.woocommerce-product-details__short-description .ukryj-klase-krotki{
    display: none;
}

.woocommerce-product-details__short-description .ukryj-klase-krotki ~ .ukryj-klase-krotki{
    display: block;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: *"I use it to hide errors made during importing ..."*, why are hiding the errors instead of fixing them (whatever it is). *"is it possible to write such jQuery code in PHP?"*, you would just not echo the errors that would require you to adjust core files/extension files. Or you intend to put all your output through a filter and then use regex to filter those out? You could also use CSS for this, no? `.woocommerce-product-details__short-description p + p` (should select every other p inside .woocommerce-product-details__short-description except the first one)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal In this particular case, it was faster to hide the errors, because the process of importing products from the warehouse is multi-stage and takes a long time (many, many hours - 25k+ products). I don't have extensive knowledge of PHP to know well how it works or to write a script - hence my question. The solution that I use is not applicable everywhere - for example, in the quick view of the product, which is loaded only after pressing the "Quick View" button (generates a popup with product preview). I think the solution is PHP.

Comment: I presented you 2 options: either you not [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) the error in the first place (for this you would need to know where the error is echoed). Or (I really do not recommend this option) you catch all the output in some sort of function and filter it out afterwards (for that you'd need to adjust your framework to put it through your function before returning the request to your client). I do not believe that you have other options, if you need it to be in PHP. Maybe someone experienced in wordpress can help you more.

Comment: *"In this particular case, it was faster to hide the errors ..."*, thats usually the case and its an excuse, but eventually you might run into troubles. Because you just mask the error instead of fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to understand how you can override WooCommerce template files via your active child theme.

The template to be overridden is [`single-product/short-description.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/templates/single-product/short-description.php)

Once copied to your chid theme in "woocommerce" *folder* > "single-product" *subfolder*, open/edit `short-description.php` file, and replace with:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single product short description
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 3.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

global $post;

$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

if ( ! $short_description ) {
    return;
} 

if ( $short_description && substr_count($short_description, '</p>') > 1 ) {
    $short_description = str_replace( ['<p class="', '<p>'], ['<p class="ukryj-klase-krotki ', '<p class="ukryj-klase-krotki">'], $short_description );
}

?>
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description<?php echo $class; ?>">
    <?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
</div>
```

Here, using [`substr_count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) php function, we count the number of `</p>` *(closing tags)* from product short  description, to add `ukryj-klase-krotki` as class selector to all `<p>` children tags using [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function. Tested and works.

Comment: I did everything as you wrote and unfortunately it doesn't work. Either way, I don't want to change the parent DIV class, but its children - if there are more than 1. Just like in jQuery code i wrote.

Comment: This is screen from my child theme: [link](https://i.ibb.co/KbxsgJJ/poprawnosc.png)
The effect I want to get in PHP: [link](https://i.ibb.co/ft9T8H9/przyklad.png)

Comment: I don't know if it matters but I'm using WooCommerce 5.0 and the latest PHP version

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to install a plugin** to add the script look here: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/search/header+and+footer+scripts/.

If you want to use PHP code instead you need to add the following code **inside the `functions.php` file of your active theme** (if I use it in the child theme):

```
// add custom class
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_custom_class' );
function add_custom_class() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.woocommerce-product-details__short-description:has(p:nth-of-type(2)) p').addClass('ukryj-klase-krotki');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

As suggested by the comments above you should fix the problem, as soon as possible, by changing the incorrect product data.

Comment: It's just my code inserted in PHP function - it's still jQuery. I'm looking for PHP solution - not jQuery. I wrote this code to show what I want to achieve in PHP.